# Bizar WPF error - ITfKeystrokeMgr.TestKeyUp

Tags: wpf

UPDATE: I've build a WPF app with no code behind, just put in a TextBox and a button and built it. When running this application I can see the same error in this user's machine. You can click on the button, and it works ok, but as soon as you press a key on the keyboard the application throws the same error. Should I reinstall the .Net Framework? Any other recommendations?

Original question:
I have a WPF app distributed via ClickOnce in an enterprise environment. Dozens of users are running my app without issues. However there's 1 single user who can't run the app. If I log-in in his machine I also get an error. The error for the user is the standard error message when any exception occurs. So I needed to remote-debug it.

The program loads without issues and it places the focus on a TextBox as soon as the TextBox looses the focus or the user presses a key, the program crashes.

I've attached my visual studio to the my application running on the problematic machine and I managed to capture the following stack trace.

"   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.ITfKeystrokeMgr.TestKeyUp(Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam, Boolean& eaten)
   at System.Windows.Input.TextServicesContext.Keystroke(Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam, KeyOp op)
   at System.Windows.Input.TextServicesManager.TextServicesKeystroke(TextServicesContext context, KeyEventArgs keyArgs, Boolean test)
   at System.Windows.Input.TextServicesManager.PreProcessInput(Object sender, PreProcessInputEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()\r\n   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawKeyboardActions actions, Int32 scanCode, Boolean isExtendedKey, Boolean isSystemKey, Int32 virtualKey)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.ProcessKeyAction(MSG& msg, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.CriticalTranslateAccelerator(MSG& msg, ModifierKeys modifiers)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessage(Object param)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, Object arg)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessageThunk(MSG& msg, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.WeakEventPreprocessMessage.OnPreprocessMessage(MSG& msg, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.ComponentDispatcherThread.RaiseThreadMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
  at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at TIS.SamSeek.WpfClient.App.Main()"

I get a System.Argument exception with the description: "Value does not fall within the expected range.".

InnerException: null
Source: WindowsBase
TargetSite: {Void TestKeyUp(Int32, Int32, Boolean ByRef)}
DeclaringType: {Name = "ITfKeystrokeMgr" FullName = "MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods+ITfKeystrokeMgr"} 
    Assembly: {WindowsBase, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35}
    Declaring method: '((System.Type)(((System.Reflection.MemberInfo)(((System.Exception)($exception)).TargetSite)).DeclaringType)).DeclaringMethod' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    Message: "Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true."
    source: "mscorlib"

I put all kinds of traces in the code and I am pretty sure that my code is not directly causing this exception. I do not have any KeyUp events in my code.

What do you suggest?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Psychic Debugger says it's something to do with the tablet input service. Office tends to install weird versions of it, which cause problems. What version of Windows is it?

Comment: Paul, thanks for your help. It is running on XP Pro SP3. You may be on to something because I can see the language bar showing with handwriting recognition options. Do you have any other suggestions on what I could be looking for? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Paul, you gave me a great hint. The Windows language bar had handwriting and voice recognition options turned on. When I turned these options off my app works fine!
What's up with that??!?!?!?!

Comment: I think it's a known bug, I had a machine where whenever I plugged in a tablet, all my WPF apps would crash

Comment: I am glad you read my question and gave me your input. I would not have caught that on my own. Thanks again.

Comment: The user has a handwriting recognition pen that writes on regular paper. I assume the handwriting recognition piece is that same that runs on a tablet.